How to get the size of an EXE file via its header data?
I am checking the EXE file spec doc at :
https://github.com/libyal/libexe/blob/main/documentation/Executable%20(EXE)%20file%20format.asciidoc, it shows the DOS MZ Header contains :

Number of bytes in last 512-byte page of executable, assume V1
Total number of 512-byte pages in executable, assume V2

So I use V2 * 512 + V1, but the size is much smaller than the actual EXE file size, why?

I assume you are actually reading a PE file.
Every PE file begins with a very small executable that only prints something like
This program must be run under Win64

The size you find in the MZ header is the size of this executable. Use the e_lfanew field in the MZ header to skip to the PE header to find the real data.
See also

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2002/february/inside-windows-win32-portable-executable-file-format-in-detail
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2002/march/inside-windows-an-in-depth-look-into-the-win32-portable-executable-file-format-part-2

